# IE on XP does not support SNI to permit multiple certificates for single server

Tags: apache, internet-explorer, https, sni

I've been searching for a few hours to find a solution to my question/problem and whilst I believe that I have been able to clarify the reason why I have problems I have been unable to find a resolution.

I have one server which is hosting multiple web sites and a couple of these web sites are using SSL certificates. I have some shared images accessed by all sites and the way to stop the none-secure error on the SSL site was to serve those shared images from https://www.example-shared-image-server.com/images/imagename.jpg

This worked fine, until that is I noticed that by using Internet Explorer on Windows XP it is giving the message "There is a problem with this website's security certificate". What I then identified is that its because its picking up a certificate for a different domain on the server. Its all to do with hosting multiple sites on one server with SSL certificates.

Lets say I have four sites with only the first two with SSL certificates installed.

```
https://www.one.com
https://www.two.com
http://www.three.com
http://www.four.com
```

And lets not forget the following:

```
https://www.example-shared-image-server.com
```

So when accessing images from the above shared image URL it is actually bringing up https://www.one.com, hence the error.

So its seems to be something to do with IE not supporting SNI or SSL/TLS on Windows XP or Vista whereas it is on Win 7 and Win 8. This seems like an immediate ploy by M$ to force people to upgrade to more current operating systems. But the fact is that all other browsers support it.

But, what I have not been able to identify is what I can do about it. So I believe my question is, is it possible to host multiple web sites using SSL on the same server on different domains without causing IE to show errors. If not, what do other people do? And it yes, how do I configure it?

I have been on this for hours so if someone could help, I would really appreciate it.

Many thanks,

Rob

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Windows XP's version of SChannel does not support SNI, which means that IE and other WinINET/WinHTTP-based applications do not support SNI on that platform.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2009/12/07/certificate-name-mismatch-warnings-and-server-name-indication.aspx

SNI support was introduced in Windows Vista; if you're not seeing it work on that platform, it's likely that IE was reconfigured away from the defaults to enable SSL2. SSLv2-compatible handshakes do not carry TLS extensions like the SNI extension.

The only real workarounds here are to either:

1. Host each server on a different IP or port (so the server can select the certificate based on that information)
2. Use a certificate that contains multiple hostnames using the SubjectAltName field of the certificate

Comment: @Craig if you have a public site its kinda hard to just tell them that xp isn't supported, instead I would start serving with http then redirect to https if its not XP.

Comment: "start serving with http" is insecure.

Comment: @EricLaw sure you loose some security but I don't see any other solution if you want to keep your ie XP users..

Comment: @Peter :-)  Unfortunately, no version of IE that works on Windows XP can even run modern web sites. Chrome still installs on XP, doesn't it? According to http://www.w3counter.com/globalstats.php, Windows XP itself only accounts for 6% of all the machines on the Internet now, and IE 8 only accounts for 2% of all web browsers in use. Is 2% really a market segment worth continuing to pursue? It likely costs you more to make your site fully functional on that measly 2% of grossly obsolete web browsers than you earn from that effort.

Comment: @Craig The good news is that both XP and IE today seem to be substantially less popular today: under 3% for XP and well under 1% for IE8 according to w3counter.com. That is progress, I suspect.

Comment: @RBerteig Agreed, and thank goodness, and it's about time...  ;-)