# Any workaround to run SNI supported sites on windows xp and IE8

Tags: ssl, sni

This question is asked multiple time and there are well briefed answers, [IE on XP does not support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18495123/ie-on-xp-does-not-support-sni-to-permit-multiple-certificates-for-single-server)

But we have problem that we have not enough public ips to assign for individual ssl based url. 
I have very basic question that can we run SNI sites(that points to single ip) on windowsXP and IE8.

We have some workarounds like, buy an other pool of IPS but that will really cost us a lot. 
Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only way to have multiple certificates on the same IP and port is to use SNI, and this needs a browser which can do SNI. Because you usually don't have control about the client you cannot force them to upgrade windows or use another browser on the same platform.

So if you really need to support multiple certificates on a single IP and cannot use SNI, your only option is to have the http server listen on different ports and setup the certificates based on the port. Note, that this might give you other problems, because non-standard port for https might be blocked by firewalls.

Comment: thats mean i need to setup separate Apache instance for each site.

Comment: Apache httpd can be configured to listen on multiple ports, and with different certs per the doc.

Another possibility is to have one cert that covers all your hostnames, using wildcard or SAN aka 'multidomain', but CAs often charge more for this. E.g. stackoverflow/*.stackexchange use one cert which has SAN including: 
*.stackexchange.com
stackexchange.com
meta.stackexchange.com
stackoverflow.com
*.stackoverflow.com
stackauth.com
sstatic.net
*.sstatic.net
serverfault.com
meta.serverfault.com
superuser.com
meta.superuser.com
stackapps.com
openid.stackauth.com
*.meta.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1):

The workarounds are.
1) make the default site one that tells people that internet explorer on XP is not supported, and is insecure, and to download firefox or chrome, and provides download links. This will hopefully convert customers to using the other browsers.
2) use different ports.

The muiti-domain cert will not help because only the first site in apache on port 443 on that ip will come up.

Answer (score 0):

I know that this is a dollar late and a day short, but you could use a [Multiple Domain (UCC) SSL certificate](https://www.godaddy.com/help/what-is-a-multiple-domain-ucc-ssl-certificate-3908).

They are a little more expensive, but you can specify multiple domain names on one certificate.